# Issue in opening a module

Tags: outsystems

I am working on OutSystems Development Environment 9.0.0.7.
Multiple developers are working on the same module.
The issue is when I am trying to publish my work, it is asking me if I want to Merge and Publish My work with other’s changes.
If click Merge and publish, it kicks me out saying
[image]

The More information is,

`System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at ServiceStudio.ViewImplementation.Framework.ProgressDialog.RunWorkerThread(PresenterContext presenterContext, Action optionalPreOperationThatCanBeSafelyAborted, Action1 operation, Action customPreOperationAborter)
   at ServiceStudio.ViewImplementation.WPFViewImplementationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4b.<DoVerySlowOperation>b__49()
   at ServiceStudio.ViewImplementation.WPFViewImplementationProvider.DoSlowOperation[ReturnType](IAggregatorView aggregatorView, Func1 operation)
   at ServiceStudio.ViewImplementation.WPFViewImplementationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4b.<DoVerySlowOperation>b__48()
   at ServiceStudio.WPFExtensions.WpfExtensions.ExecuteInUIThread[ReturnType](Application app, Func1 action)
   at ServiceStudio.ViewImplementation.WPFViewImplementationProvider.ExecuteInUIThread[ReturnType](Func1 action)
   at ServiceStudio.ViewImplementation.WPFViewImplementationProvider.DoVerySlowOperation(IAggregatorView aggregatorView, String title, Action1 optionalPreOperationThatCanBeSafelyAborted, Action 1 operation, Action customPreOperationAborter)
   at ServiceStudio.Presenter.RuntimeImplementation.#jq13.#pao()
   at ServiceStudio.Presenter.AggregatorPresenter.DisableCommandProcessingIn(Action action)
   at ServiceStudio.Presenter.RuntimeImplementation.DoVerySlowOperation(IAggregatorPresenter aggregator, String title, Action1 optionalPreOperationThatCanBeSafelyAborted, Action1 operation, Action customPreOperationAborter)
   at ServiceStudio.Presenter.AggregatorPresenter.#hok.#wNn()`

Tried reinstalling the development Environment. Tried logging in using the other users credentials. Nothing seems to be working.I can open the other modules still. Not sure what the issue is, Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not your fault, it is an OutSystems Platform bug. I suggest you contact outsystems support for help, or if you prefer you can contact me directly using a private message.

Regards